# Is there any way to return to the main menu?

Tags: c++, function, menu

I want to write a C++ program involving open menus.

```
void mainmenu(){
    //some code
    if (a==1){return menu2();}
}
void menu2(){
    //some code
    if (b==1){return menu3();}
}

void menu3(){
    //some code
    if (c==1) //from here, I want to return to the main menu(restart the program)
}

int main(){
    mainmenu();
}
```

Is there any way to return to the main menu from menu3?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course write is recursively (directly calling `menuX()` from each choice), but this is bad practice due to far too many reasons.

Better make each function return the option selected, and add an infinite loop in main code:

```
void mainmenu(){
    //some code
    if (a==1){return 2;}
}
void menu2(){
    //some code
    if (b==1){return 3;}
}

void menu3(){
    //some code
    if (c==1) {return 0;}
}

int main(){
    int menu = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (menu == 0) { menu = mainmenu(); }
        else if (menu == 1) { menu = menu1(); }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call mainmenu() in menu3() definition if c ==1

Comment: It doesn't restart the program. After the second mainmenu() terminated, it will return to the menu3() again.